# How does the size of a water drop varies between materials?

Tags: water, material-science, surface-tension

Say you have rising steam forming water on some surface and when the water accumulates, it forms a drop that falls because of (I suppose? Not sure) Mass exceeding the force of surface tension.

Does the material on which the steam gathers influence the size of the drop when its mass is heavy enough to make it fall ? If yes (pretty sure it does), what criteria allows to calculate that specific point where a drop is too heavy to hold onto a surface ?

Comment: yes; the material on which the steam accumulates determines the contact angle made by the vapor bubble/droplet. falling of the droplet will then happen when the droplet weight > component of surface tension force along the material surface.

Comment: Then which materials forms the smallest and the largest drops ?

Comment: in my earlier comment, I tried to answer the second part of your question. The point when the droplet falls down from the surface can be different when placed on different materials.

Comment: I do not have an answer about the first part of your question concerning the drop size.